# Changing fonts for foreign languages with font-face in css3?

Tags: html, css, font-face

Is it possible to change an Arabic font to one that I pick using font-face in css3 ?
I tried it with English and it works , I know it will defer with foreign languages so I needed to ask .
and , I know this question is so dumb but since I never wrote inside a website with Arabic , how can I do that in HTML ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work with any character-set. A recommendation is that you also set the charset to utf-8, to avoid compatibility issues - although it should work regardless.